# 2.78b : Blender system Cloud texture addon not showing

Tags: add-on, blender-id

1. Just subscribed to Blender Cloud
2. Downloaded addon: https://cloud.blender.org/services
3. Able to login via Blender Cloud id(This one was already installed with 2.78b - so dont know why it is included in the download addon)
4. Install from file. But I don't see any "System Blender cloud texture"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Blender ID add-on was first bundled with Blender in 2.78; it was included with the Blender Cloud add-on to allow people with Blender 2.77 to use it too.

To get to the Texture Browser, the easiest way is to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. Alternatively, in the UV/Image editor, choose 'Image' > 'Get Image from Blender Cloud'.

[The documentation](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/System/BlenderCloud) is available from the add-on screen itself, and describes some of the other features too (like Blender Sync):

[image]